# How to pass request to Celery task parameter in Django project?

Tags: django, task, celery

I am using `wkhtmltopdf` with Django to generate a PDF file and email it to someone. Here is my view:

```
class ChallanEmail(AtomicMixin, View, LoginRequiredMixin):
    template = "europarts/challan/email_template.html"

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        challan = Challan.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        ref_no = challan.ref_no
        date = challan.created
        recipient = challan.recipient
        address = challan.recipient_address
        challan_rows = ChallanRow.objects.filter(challan=challan)

        context = {
            "ref_no": ref_no,
            "date": date,
            "recipient": recipient,
            "address": address,
            "challan_rows": challan_rows,
        }

        response = PDFTemplateResponse(
            request=request,
            template=self.template,
            filename='challan_email.pdf',
            context=context,
            show_content_in_browser=True,
            cmd_options={'margin-top': 10,
                         'zoom': 1,
                         'viewport-size': '1366 x 513',
                         'javascript-delay': 1000,
                         'no-stop-slow-scripts': True},
        )

        file_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'challan_email.pdf')
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.rendered_content)

        subject = 'From Design Ace Limited'
        body = self.request.GET.get('email_body', '')
        from_email = 'Sorower Hossain <sorower@europartsbd.com>'
        to = ['{}'.format(self.request.GET.get('to_address'))]
        attachment = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'challan_email.pdf')

        send_email(subject, body, from_email, to, attachment)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('europarts:challan_details', args=(kwargs['pk'],)))
```

As you can see towards the end I am sending the email with a task (`send_email`) using `celery`. However, the most time consuming process is the PDF creation process. Here is the portion of code that does that:

```
response = PDFTemplateResponse(
    request=request,
    template=self.template,
    filename='challan_email.pdf',
    context=context,
    show_content_in_browser=True,
    cmd_options={'margin-top': 10,
                 'zoom': 1,
                 'viewport-size': '1366 x 513',
                 'javascript-delay': 1000,
                 'no-stop-slow-scripts': True},
    )
```

The problem I am facing is whenever I am trying to transfer all the parameters to a celery task, it shows an error because `request` is not serializable. How can I transfer the request to my celery task and save time in PDF generation? It takes almost three seconds for this task which is a lot.

Comment: You are generating PDF only to send it by email?

Comment: @SzymonP. Yes, I have to send an attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `PDFTemplateResponse` only to generate pdf file and sent it by email (not as http response), you can mock it in celery task.

Your celery task, in `<app_name>/tasks.py` file:

```
from django.test.client import RequestFactory
# other necessary imports
...

@shared_task
def create_pdf_and_send_email(template, context, email_body, to_address):
    request = RequestFactory().get('') # any valid url
    challan_rows = ChallanRow.objects.filter(pk__in=context['challan_rows'])
    context['challan_rows'] = challan_rows
    response = PDFTemplateResponse(
            request=request,
            template=template,
            filename='challan_email.pdf',
            context=context,
            show_content_in_browser=True,
            cmd_options={'margin-top': 10,
                         'zoom': 1,
                         'viewport-size': '1366 x 513',
                         'javascript-delay': 1000,
                         'no-stop-slow-scripts': True},
        )

        file_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'challan_email.pdf')
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.rendered_content)

        subject = 'From Design Ace Limited'
        body = email_body
        from_email = 'Sorower Hossain <sorower@europartsbd.com>'
        to = ['{}'.format(to_address)]
        attachment = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'challan_email.pdf')
        send_email(subject, body, from_email, to, attachment)
```

And your refactored `get` method:

```
from .tasks import create_pdf_and_send_email
...
def get(self, request, **kwargs):
    challan = Challan.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
    ref_no = challan.ref_no
    date = challan.created
    recipient = challan.recipient
    address = challan.recipient_address
    challan_rows = ChallanRow.objects.filter(challan=challan).values_list('pk', flat=True)

    context = {
        "ref_no": ref_no,
        "date": date,
        "recipient": recipient,
        "address": address,
        "challan_rows": challan_rows,
    }

    email_body = self.request.GET.get('email_body', '')
    to_address = self.request.GET.get('to_address')
    create_pdf_and_send_email.delay(template, context, email_body, to_address)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('europarts:challan_details', args=(kwargs['pk'],)))
```

I hope that it should works.

If there will be any problems with serialization errors (possible with `address` field in `context` variable), change `address = challan.recipient_address` to `address = challan.recipient_address.pk` in `get` method.
Then, inside celery task, retrieve address with given pk (e.g. `address = YourAddressModel.objects.get(pk=context['address'])`, and replace `context['address']` with `context['address'] = address`.

Comment: Using `RequestFactory` solved my issue, however, now it says `<QuerySet [<ChallanRow: 456>]> is not JSON serializable`. I am guessing my queryset needs to be passed a different way.

Comment: Is this the only way to do? for this purpose